# How to partition a set in order to minimize the number of the elements and their interactions?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, knapsack-problems

Given two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $n$ elements each. Each set $S_1$ (resp. $S_2$) has a revenue $R_1$ (resp. $R_2$). Each element $i$ of $S_1$ (resp. $S_2$) has a gain $g_{i1}$ (resp. $g_{i2}$). From set $S_1$ (resp. $S_2$), choose a subset of elements $O_1$ (and $O_2$) such that:

- $\sum_{i\in O_1}g_{i1}\geqslant R_1$;
- $\sum_{i\in O_2}g_{i2}\geqslant R_2$;
- $|O_1|+|O_2|+|O_1\cap O_2|$ is minimized.

Can we solve this problem in polynomial-time?

I started by a greedy approach which chooses the elements by increasing order of their gains. I tried few examples but this does not provide optimal results.

I am now trying to prove that it is NP-hard using a reduction from PARTITION. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two variants of subset sum problem:

## Variant 1

> Given a set of $2n$ positive integer elements and a positive integer target $W$, is there a subset with size $n$, whose sum is $W$?

## Variant 2

> Given a set of $n$ positive integer elements and a positive integer target $W$, where $(\text{the maximum element})< 2\times(\text{the minimum element})$, is there a subset whose sum is $W$?

Variant 1 is NP-hard by a reduction from [one-in-three 3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability) (almost [the same reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10703/83244) from 3SAT to the normal subset sum problem, except that we do not need the $s$ and $t$ values, and the target is always $111\ldots1$).

Variant 2 is also NP-hard by a reduction from Variant 1. Given an instance of Variant 1, we add a large enough integer $M$ to each element so that the new elements satisfy the constraint in Variant 2. Now the answer to Variant 1 is "yes" if and only if there is a subset of the new elements whose sum is $W+nM$ (since $M$ is large enough, the subset must have size $n$).

Now we show a reduction from Variant 2 to (the decision version of) your problem, so your problem is NP-hard.

Given an instance of Variant 2, we construct $S_1=S_2$ as the same set as the given instance. Let $s$ denote the sum of all elements. We set $R_1=W$ and $R_2=s-W$. The gain of each element is the same as itself.

Now if there is a subset $O\subseteq S_1=S_2$ whose sum is $W$, then we can choose $O_1=O$ and $O_2=S_2\backslash O$, meaning there is a solution to your problem with $|O_1|+|O_2|+|O_1\cap O_2|\le n$.

On the other hand, if there is a solution to your problem with $|O_1|+|O_2|+|O_1\cap O_2|\le n$, then $2|O_1\cap O_2|\le n-|O_1\cup O_2|$. Let $\min$ and $\max$ be the minimum and maximum elements respectively. We have
$$\sum_{e\in O_1\cap O_2}e\le |O_1\cap O_2|\max\le 2|O_1\cap O_2|\min\le(n-|O_1\cup O_2|)\min\le\sum_{e\notin O_1\cup O_2}e.$$

This means
$$
\sum_{e\notin O_1}e=\sum_{e\in O_2}e-\sum_{e\in O_1\cap O_2}e+\sum_{e\notin O_1\cup O_2}e\ge \sum_{e\in O_2}e\ge s-W.
$$

Note $\sum_{e\in O_1}e\ge W$ and $\sum_{e\notin O_1}e+\sum_{e\in O_1}e=s$, we have $\sum_{e\in O_1}e=W$ and $\sum_{e\notin O_1}e =s-W$, which means there is a subset $O\subseteq S_1=S_2$ whose sum is $W$.

Comment: Thanks. Is the variant 2 known in the literature? Do you mean that the gains are constructed so that the max gain is at most twice the min gain?

Comment: @zdm The max gain is at most twice the min gain because so is the input of Variant 2, not because of the construction. I don't think Variant 2 is studied in the literature because it is trivial.

Comment: In the reduction from Variant 1 to Variant 2, say I have an instance of Variant 1 as follows: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $W=11$. How can I choose $M$ ?

Comment: @zdm It is enough to let $M$ be the sum of all elements. In your example we can choose $M=21$.

Comment: I tried some examples with your reduction. Given an instance of Variant 2, when I create an instance of my problem I always find a solution with $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$. Does this mean that the problem is still NP-hard even if I want to minimize $|O_1|+|O_2|$?

Comment: @zdm No. There are three conditions involved: 1. $|O_1|+|O_2|+|O_1\cap O_2|$ is minimized; 2. $|O_1|+|O_2|+|O_1\cap O_2|$ is minimized and $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$, which is equivalent to $|O_1|+|O_2|$ is minimized and $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$; 3. $|O_1|+|O_2|$ is minimized. The problem under condition 1 or condition 2 is NP-hard, but not under condition 3. In fact, you can simply minimize $|O_1|$ and $|O_2|$ separately to minimize $|O_1|+|O_2|$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Can you provide an example of variant 2 for which we have a solution to the problem and $O_1\cap O_2\ne\emptyset$?.

Comment: @zdm No. The issue is that even if there is no solution to Variant 2, we can have $|O_1|+|O_2|\le n$. For example, consider {10, 12, 14, 16, 18} and target 33, the optimal solution to your problem is $O_1=\{16, 18\}$ and $O_2=\{14, 16, 18\}$,